# What is the term for referring to an action or phenomenon using somebody's name without an obvious comparator ('like' ...) – eg 'Doing a Lord Lucan'?

Tags: grammar, slang

A friend of mine is keen on taking the glory (or adverse publicity!) when something goes wrong on a job he's working on and he likes to give it his name, e.g., "this is turning into a right Simpson of a job […]."

So I suppose my question is two fold:

- What do you call it when somebody does this?
- What is the grammatical description for the name when used in this context?

Comment: In other words, the question is about using a proper name instead of an adjective, as saying "you are an Alfred," instead of "you are an ingenuous." (The example is abstract; nobody says "Alfred" to mean an ingenous person.)

Comment: This is a Charlie Brown of a business

Comment: Several Mickey Mouse banks were based in Iceland.

Answer (score 4):

The term for this concept is *[eponym](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/eponym)*. From TheFreeDictionary:

> **ep·o·nym**  (p-nm)
>   *n*.
>   1. A word or name derived from the name of a person. The words *atlas*, *bowdlerize*, and *Turing machine* are eponyms.
>   2. A person whose name is or is thought to be the source of the name of something.

I don't know if there's a verb that describes this process. Probably "making an eponym" would be the closest.

**Edit**: @JSBangs deftly suggests *eponymize* in the comments below, and that sounds good to me.

Comment: By analogy with other words formed with *-nym*, the verb should probably be *eponymize*.

Comment: @JSBangs: Good thought.

Comment: Possibly. He's not directly 'naming' anything though, it's more of a phrase...he's saying something like "doing a Lord Lucan" to describe disappearing.

Comment: There's a whopping big list of 'em over at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_eponyms).

Comment: [Here](http://www.google.co.uk/#q=eponymised&hl=en&newwindow=1&tbm=bks&ei=0FEGT7a8Ncjb8APq-oDLAQ&start=0&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=c9295a07f232d5d4&biw=1144&bih=857) are at least a couple of dozen instances of *eponymised*, though I must admit several suggest confusion with [epitomised](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/epitomise)