# Word to describe applying human name to actions

Tags: single-word-requests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the term for giving an action or phenomenon somebody's name, e.g. “Doing a Lord Lucan”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32097/what-is-the-term-for-giving-an-action-or-phenomenon-somebodys-name-e-g-doing)

Is there a word to describe applying a human name to actions? For example, if you had a friend called Tony who consistently got too drunk and threw up everywhere, then you could describe somebody performing those actions as *tonying*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word is [*eponym*](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=off&q=eponym&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=OUYGT7zlKMXs0gHh-LCxAg&ved=0CB0QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=4b3c420078196b39&biw=1024&bih=683).  It can actually go both ways, referring to the namesake or the derived word:

> 1. A person after whom a discovery, invention, place, etc., is named or thought to be named
> 2. A name or noun formed in such a way

Answer (score 0):

Words formed in this way are '[eponyms](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eponym#English)'.