# What is the name of this rhetorical device: Using the plural of a proper name (or even proper noun) to generalize?

Tags: grammatical-number

I hear this a great deal from sportscasters:

> Crowds will pay to see the Ohtanis and Trouts...

Making a plural out of a person's name seems to create a general form, almost as one had said,

> Crowds will pay to see *stars like* Ohtani and Trout.

Does this rhetorical device have a name?

Comment: I can't make a relevant answer out of it, but an [eponym](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/eponym) is the name of an object or activity that is also the name of the person who first produced the object or did the activity.

Comment: Plurals are always bigger than singulars, no matter what. And advertising is all about bigger is better.

Comment: I still can't make an answer because mainstream dictionaries do not seem to contain **iconify**.

Comment: Closely related: [What is the term for referring to an action or phenomenon using  somebody's name – eg doing a Lord Lucan?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32097/what-is-the-term-for-giving-an-action-or-phenomenon-somebodys-name-e-g-doing/32099#32099)

Comment: @Weather Vane [AHD and R H K Webster's](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/eponym) give wider definitions of 'eponym'; I'm sure 'Ohtanis' = 'people with certain salient attributes / talents ... similar to some of Shohei Ohtani's' qualifies. 'The Napoleon of crime' is a related and better known  example. And 'He is no Arthur.'

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if has a name as a rhetorical device, but Douglas Hofstadter and Emmanuel Sander eloquently comment on this type of plural in [*Surfaces and Essences: Analogy as the Fuel and Fire of Thinking*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Surfaces_and_Essences/92e30rzcoCkC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22We%20humans%20construct%20categories,%20extend%20them%22) (2013):

> We humans construct categories, extend them, multiply them, link them
> together, and glide gracefully among them. If we think in a subtle
> fashion, it is due to the richness of our repertoire of concepts and
> to our flexibility in seeing freshly-encountered situations in terms
> of our concepts. We categorize in ways that go well beyond the most
> common meaning of the term "categorize", for not only do we categorize
> objects, actions, and situations in preexisting categories, but at the
> drop of a hat we transform any already-perceived entity into a
> category, **a process exemplified by proper nouns that are run through
> the categorization mill and emerge as full-fledged plurals—ranging
> from one's sister to the corner druggist, from Lincolns to Leonardos,
> from Picassos to Puccinis, from Mozarts to Mataharis**. To put it in a
> nutshell, we humans are compulsive category-extenders, insatiable
> tourists who cannot get enough of the world of categories, old hands at
> semantic slippages, similarity-spotters par excellence, and last but
> not least, inveterate abstractors. (p.254)

They do, however, give a name, **canonization**, to a closely related construct:

> A catchy French song called "Le Piano du pauvre" by singer-composer
> Léo Ferré describes a random Parisian street-accordionist as "le
> Chopin du printemps"—"the Chopin of the springtime". **Both the
> anonymous accordionist and Frédéric Chopin are being honored here—the
> former for being an "instance" of the latter, and the latter for having
> been turned into a category that can have instances. We will call this
> latter honor "canonization"**. Of course, thousands of people besides
> Chopin have been canonized. As a matter of fact, with a bit of effort
> one can turn up scads of colorful expression based on  canonizations,
> such as the following seventy-odd mind-boggling examples (none of
> which, believe it or not, was dreamt up by your authors):
>
> > the Bach of the vibraphone, the Beethoven of landscape painting, the Haydn of chess, the Mozart of mushrooms, the Mendelssohn of Hinduism, the Puccini of pop, the Wagner of rock, the Billie Holiday of ballet, the Benny Goodman of duck-calling...the Sherlock Holmes of Yiddish music... (p.221)

Comment: As a long-time fan, I'll gladly give an upvote for anyone referencing Hofstadter.

Answer (score 2):

The phenomenon you mention is not purely rhetorical.  Authors of classical Latin, for example, would use what I would call a pluralisation of proper names, which we could call *generic*.  Just as we can talk of 'the Einsteins' or 'the Hitlers' of this world, meaning people like Einstein (extraordinarily brilliant) or like Hitler (extraordinarily evil or dangerous) so did the Romans.  It can obviously be used rhetorically with a sneer, if the use is derogatory.

Comment: I've just checked on 'rhetorical devices'  ([Jericho Writers](https://jerichowriters.com/what-is-a-rhetorical-device-and-how-to-use-them/) has a good article) and agree that 'literary device', not requiring the persuasive/hortative factor, is more suitable here.

Answer (score 2):

English has (at least) three types of [Generic Noun Phrases](http://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/000001.html), which do not refer to a thing in an ordinary fashion, like most noun phrases:

- *The crow on the fence is looking at you strangely.*

but rather refer to groups, in various ways.

- ***The crow** is a very intelligent bird.* (singular definite NP)
- ***Crows** live and feed in groups.* (plural NP)
- ***A crow** has a low call.* (singular indefinite NP)

These are (respectively) called the Definite Generic, the Plural Generic, and the Indefinite Generic noun phrases. Definite generics refer to species, plural generics refer to tendencies, and indefinite generics refer to defining characteristics. That's why

- *The quartet requires 4 voices*
- *Quartets require 4 voices*
- *A quartet requires 4 voices*

are all correct and grammatical, like

- *The quartet is popular*
- *Quartets are popular*

but not

- **A quartet is popular*

because being popular is not a characteristic of a quartet.

Comment: Following your line of thought, the following appear to work for me:
The Ohtani is a rare bird.
(The) Ohtanis of the world both pitch and hit.
An Ohtani commands a large salary.